# Google Charts Data View set columns dynamically

Tags: javascript, csv, google-visualization

I am using google charts to render the data on webpages. I am using a CSV as an input and that data is then manipulated for google chart api to use.

I want to show the column value on the top of the Bar/Column chart. I figured out that if you create a Data View and do view.setColumns and specify the role annotation then number becomes visible on the top of the chart, otherwise you need to hover on the chart to see the exact value.

My problem is that i am unable to dynamically set the columns and roles to the view. As the input is csv, i will never be sure about the columns.

Main intent is to show the numbers on the bars, if there is any other alternative by which it can be done, then it will be appreciated as well. Cheers

```
var arrayData = csvAttr.toArrays(csvString, {
                onParseValue : csvAttr.hooks.castToScalar
            });

var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

             view.setColumns([0, 1,
                               { calc: "stringify",
                                 sourceColumn: 1,
                                 type: "string",
                                 role: "annotation" },
                               2,
                               { calc: "stringify",
                                     sourceColumn: 2,
                                     type: "string",
                                     role: "annotation" },
                                3,
                                { calc: "stringify",
                                     sourceColumn: 3,
                                     type: "string",
                                     role: "annotation" }

                               ]);
```

Comment: help me understand why you can't dynamically `setColumns`. is it because you don't know how many columns exist in the file? do the charts always work? seems like the first one or two columns would need to be row labels, and the remaining columns row values. any set structure to the CSV files?

Comment: @WhiteHat, don't worry. I could use the jquery csv to find the columns etc and was able to set the data dynamically. It was end of the day for me, may be i was worn out resolving a lot of other things.  I have resolved it. Thanks for looking.

Comment: cheers! been there...

Answer (score 0):

Simple way for set columns dynamically.

```
var totalColumns = 3  
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable); 
var columns = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= totalColumns ; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
        columns.push(i);
        columns.push({
            calc: "stringify",
            sourceColumn: 1,
            type: "string",
            role: "annotation"
        });

    } else {
        columns.push(i);
    }
}

view.setColumns(columns);
```

Comment: Should be `sourceColumn: i,`

Comment: Be aware that although `totalColumns = 3` and `i <= totalColumns` are correct for the example of the original post, "totalColumns" is not the number of total columns in original data table (3 vs 4). If you think of totalColumns are the number of all the columns including the indepedent (zero indexed) column you should use `i < totalColumns` instead of `i <= totalColumns`